# arbitrary order differentiation of a product of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> I have a function of the form
>
> $$ F(z) = G(z)^a H(z)^b$$
>   where $ G(z) = \sqrt{1-Qz} + \sqrt{1-Q},$
>   $ H(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-Qz}}{z}$,
>   and $a$, $b$, $Q$ are non-integer constants. This function arises as a probability generating function for a random variable, so I need to compute
>
> $$ p(n) = \frac{1}{n!}F^{(n)}(0+)$$
>   to determine the probability mass function $p(n)$.
>   How can I best compute $F^{(n)}(z)$?

---

**Ideas:**

One idea is to figure out $G^{(n)}(z)$ and $H^{(n)}(z)$, then figure out how recursive application of the product rule leads to an expression of $F^{(n)}(z)$ in terms of these.

So far I have the general Leibniz rule
$$ [f(z)g(z)]^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f^{(n-k)}(z)g^{(k)}(z),$$
and the derivatives
$$ G^{(n)} (z) = - \big(\frac{Q}{2}\big)^n (2n-1)!! (1-Qz)^{-(2n-1)/2}. $$
I'll update as I make more progress...

Any pointers for me to solve this repeated differentiation problem?

Comment: what is $Q{}{}{}$ (and they are algebraic not rational functions)

Comment: Q is a constant

Comment: For $a$ rational they are algebraic functions otherwise they are not

Answer (score 1):

Then $$(1+Qz)^{a/2} = \sum_{k \ge 0} {a/2 \choose m} Q^m z^m$$ where ${a/2 \choose m}  = \prod_{j=1}^m \frac{a/2-(j-1)}{j}$ and $$(fg)^{(k)}= \sum_{l=0}^k {k \choose l} f^{(l)} g^{(k-l)}$$

Comment: It's more complex than this! There's still the product and power functions involved